# Regex to find first and last date from string : output 12/31/2018 and 12/1/2018

Tags: regex

I have a comma separated date string and need to extract the first and last date from it using regex. Eg : (Day = 12/31/2018:Monday - 12/31 , 12/30/2018:Sunday - 12/30 , 12/29/2018:Saturday - 12/29 , 12/28/2018:Friday - 12/28 , 12/27/2018:Thursday - 12/27 , 12/26/2018:Wednesday - 12/26 , 12/25/2018:Tuesday - 12/25 , 12/24/2018:Monday - 12/24 , 12/23/2018:Sunday - 12/23 , 12/22/2018:Saturday - 12/22 , 12/21/2018:Friday - 12/21 , 12/20/2018:Thursday - 12/20 , 12/19/2018:Wednesday - 12/19 , 12/18/2018:Tuesday - 12/18 , 12/17/2018:Monday - 12/17 , 12/16/2018:Sunday - 12/16 , 12/15/2018:Saturday - 12/15 , 12/14/2018:Friday - 12/14 , 12/13/2018:Thursday - 12/13 , 12/12/2018:Wednesday - 12/12 , 12/11/2018:Tuesday - 12/11 , 12/10/2018:Monday - 12/10 , 12/9/2018:Sunday - 12/09 , 12/8/2018:Saturday - 12/08 , 12/7/2018:Friday - 12/07 , 12/6/2018:Thursday - 12/06 , 12/5/2018:Wednesday - 12/05 , 12/4/2018:Tuesday - 12/04 , 12/3/2018:Monday - 12/03 ,12/2/2018:Sunday - 12/02 , 12/1/2018:Saturday - 12/01 ).

Its ok to have 2 regex. I was able to get for the first value using '\=(.*?):' 
The second one is a little tricky and need help in finding a regex for it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share your efforts, so that we can help you in a constructive way.

Answer (score 0):

Regex search strings:

1. The first date: '\=([^,]*):'
2. The last date: '([^,^\s]*):[^,]*$'

And javascript exaple code:

```
var str = '(Day = 12/31/2018:Monday - 12/31 , 12/30/2018:Sunday - 12/30 , 12/2/2018:Sunday - 12/02 , 12/1/2018:Saturday - 12/01 ).';
var rg1 = /\=([^,]*):/;
var rg2 = /([^,^\s]*):[^,]*$/;
var match1 = rg1.exec(str);
var match2 = rg2.exec(str);
alert('First date is = "' + match1[1] + '", last date is "' + match2[1] + '"');
```